# How to use an `Arraylist` in `OnClick` method?

Tags: java, android, onclick

When I try to use an `ArrayList`, and `StringBuffer` in `OnClick` method, Android studio wants me to change them to `final`. But when I do that, I can only keep the last inserted element in `ArrayList`.

```java
SharedPreferences sp = mContext.getSharedPreferences("checked",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor e=sp.edit();
        final ArrayList<Integer> sharedP= new ArrayList<>();

        final String word = words.get(position).getMean();
        final int id= words.get(position).getId();
        final StringBuffer str= new StringBuffer("");

        holder.rowText.setText(word);
        holder.rowText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.rowText.isChecked()) {

                    sharedP.remove(sharedP.indexOf(id));
                    holder.rowText.setCheckMarkDrawable(null);
                    holder.rowText.setChecked(false);
                } else {

                    sharedP.add(id);
                    holder.rowText.setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.ic_check_black_24dp);
                    holder.rowText.setChecked(true);

                }

                for(int i=0;i<sharedP.size();i++){
                    Log.e("sharedpreference1",sharedP.get(i).toString());
                    str.append(sharedP.get(i));

                }

                e.putString("str", str.toString());
                e.commit();

            }

        });
```

> Updated code

```java
SharedPreferences sp = mContext.getSharedPreferences("checked",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        e=sp.edit();
        sharedP= new ArrayList<>();
        word = words.get(position).getMean();
        Log.e("getMean",word);
        id= words.get(position).getId();
        str= new StringBuffer("");

        holder.rowText.setText(word);
        holder.rowText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.rowText.isChecked()) {

                    sharedP.remove(sharedP.indexOf(word));
                    flag=false;

                    holder.rowText.setCheckMarkDrawable(null);
                    holder.rowText.setChecked(false);
                } else {

                    sharedP.add(word);
                    flag=true;
                    Log.e("deneme",word);
                    holder.rowText.setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.ic_check_black_24dp);
                    holder.rowText.setChecked(true);

                }

                str.delete(0,str.length());
                for(int i=0;i<sharedP.size();i++){
                    Log.e("sharedpreference1",sharedP.get(i).toString());
                    str.append(sharedP.get(i));
                    str.append(".");

                }
                if(flag==false){
                    e.remove("str");
                    e.commit();
                }
                Log.e("size",str.toString());
                e.putString("str", str.toString());
                e.remove("set");

                e.commit();

            }

        });
```

but it still returns the last element of Array

[example of checkedTextView](https://i.hizliresim.com/DOaYPz.png)

[shared preference](https://i.hizliresim.com/lQVqWk.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your variables outside of that method.

```
private SharedPreferences.Editor e;
private ArrayList<Integer> sharedP= new ArrayList<>();
private String word = null;
private int id= 0;
private StringBuffer str = null;
```

Then:

```
e=sp.edit();
sharedP= new ArrayList<>();
word = words.get(position).getMean();
id= words.get(position).getId();
str= new StringBuffer("");
```

Comment: it works thanks but it still returns the last element of Array

Comment: You probably don't want 'id' to be global or it will be overwritten each time you construct one.  It needs to live in the correct function scope, or you need to save it somewhere the onClickHandler can access it, like as an attribute of the rowText object

Answer (score 0):

Declare the Arraylist and the String Buffer as global variables.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> sharedP = new ArrayList<>();
private StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("");
```